Does Matthew 19:28 support the concept that Judas had salvation but lost it?
Matthew 19:28 A21
[28] Then Jesus said to them, Truly I say to you who have followed me, in the regeneration, when the Son of Man sits on his glorious throne, you also will sit on twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel.

What translation is that?  I can't find an exact match.

No, neither the idea that Judas already had salvation nor the idea that he lost it are supported by this passage.

Jesus is talking about those "who have followed me", and he already knows that Judas is not included in that number, as his heart was never fully committed.
Jesus might also know that Judas will be part of the second resurrection, and it will be at that time that Judas will be given his first and only offer of salvation.

In each case, Judas never had salvation, and so could not lose it.
In fact, none of the Disciples had salvation at this time.
Salvation wasn't possible until the Resurrection, and even then it wasn't until the events at Pentecost that God's redeeming spirit became available.

+1. The disciples began the journey of spiritual race only from the day of Pentecost. Judas didn't receive the empowering Spirit. So he is not condemned. He has a chance to repent and follow in the second resurrection. You are right.

"as his heart was never fully committed" source?

Judas Iscariot appears to have followed the same path as those who will be included on the last day, when Jesus will say, ‘I never knew you. Depart from me, you lawbreakers!’ (at the end of Matthew 7).

Judas was chosen to be one of the 12 apostles (Luke 6:12-16).

Judas was given power to do miracles like the other apostles (Matthew
10:1-4).

Judas heard the insights meant for Jesus' disciples (all the
Gospels).

Jesus knew Judas was a traitor (John 6:70,71).

Judas Iscariot was a thief (John 12:6).

Satan finally filled Judas Iscariot (John 13:2).

Jesus called Judas the Son of Ruin and said he was lost (John 17:12).

Judas gave the money back and went out to hang himself (Matthew
27:3-5).


From this scripture it is apparent Judas went his own way and did not continue to follow Jesus. From that it is inferred Judas was not saved, especially since John said he was a thief and it's clear from other scripture thieves will not be a part of God's Kingdom. Jesus also said Judas was lost.
Jesus said Judas Iscariot was lost and John the apostle said Judas was a thief. From that it appears that there are no explicit scriptures showing Judas changed his mind about Jesus. However, there's an inference Judas may have changed in Matthew 27. Yet, this is implicit and not clear to us.
Because of this I would say the answer is Judas was not saved, but there's always that unknown that only God knows the full picture about anyone (Revelation 20:13). On another note, Judas is a bad example of whether we are saved or not per his example, since it's so iffy.

In Christian concept, salvation is not an event but a process, briefly in three steps;

Justification - This is the initial step where a person accepts Jesus Christ as their Lord and Savior, and their sins are forgiven.
Sanctification - This is a lifelong journey of spiritual growth and maturity.
Glorification - This is the final step which takes place when believers are united with Christ in eternity, receiving an immortal, imperishable bodies at the resurrection.

Judas, one of Jesus' disciples, casts doubt on whether he passed the initial step. Recorded in Matthew 27:4, his final moments reveal his remorse solely for shedding innocent blood rather than acknowledging his betrayal of the Son of God. His sanctification process ended with his suicide, likely never completed.
The remaining eleven disciples appear to recognize Judas' fate as lost. In Acts 1:21-26, the election of Matthias to replace Judas is an act to fulfill the prophecy in Matthew 19:28, ensuring that there are twelve disciples occupy twelve thrones, judging the twelve tribes of Israel.

In considering this question it is important to include the verse that follows 19:28

And everyone who has given up houses or brothers or sisters or father
or mother or children or lands for the sake of my name will receive a
hundred times more, and will inherit eternal life. (NABRE)

Neither verse speaks of salvation in the sense of the standard Christian doctrine: namely that one is saved only by faith in Jesus' atoning death and resurrection. (Romans 3:24-26, etc.) In these verses, Jesus promises that any of the apostles who follow him will rule in the kingdom; and even that anyone who leaves home and family for his sake will inherit eternal life.
In these verses, Jesus does not address the possibility that one may change his mind about him or fall back into sin. In that sense, we may think of Judas as being included in the promise, but only if he fulfilled his portion of responsibility - namely if he continued in faith in Jesus and devotion to Jesus' cause.
Conclusion: Jesus' promise to Judas and the other apostles in Mt. 19 implied a responsibility for them to carry through in their commitment to him. So it was a conditional promise, one that Judas did not fulfill. Therefore in simple terms, the answer to the OP is "no."
